# Convert time 00:30:20 format to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have data coming from the database and the formate of duration for video is 
00:05:20 and want it convert to 5 minutes 20 seconds.

If hour is not present there should not be like 0 hours it should be like 5 minutes 20 seconds only.

There is  moment.js but dont want to use any plugin.

How this can be achieved using javascript or jQuery?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @nnnnn asked now ! :)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```js
function timeString(time){
  
  var timeExtract = /(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/g.exec(time);
  var totalSeconds = +timeExtract[1] * 3600 + +timeExtract[2] * 60 + +timeExtract[3];

  var result = [
    ["hour", totalSeconds/3600], 
    ["minute", totalSeconds/60], 
    ["second", totalSeconds]
  ];

  return result.map(function(timer){
    var str = timer[0], value = timer[1] | 0, left = value % 60;
    return value > 0 ? value > 1 ? left + " " + str + "s" : left + " " + str : ""
  }).join(" ")
}

document.write(timeString("00:00:20") + "<br>")
document.write(timeString("00:05:20") + "<br>")
document.write(timeString("01:05:20") + "<br>")
```

Comment: That was quick, 
Just quick question how this will handle hour like if input is 01:05:20 ?

Comment: Why are you using the `totalSec` variable instead of just using the hour, minute and seconds values directly?

Comment: Because there are situations in which for example if the string is "1:00:30", it will be: `1 hour 30 seconds` instead of `1 hour 0 minutes 30 seconds`. Say it could be a way more orderly

Answer (score 1):

This function may help you :

```
function stringify (time) { 
   var result = '';
   var date = time.split(':').map(Number);

   result += date[0] ? (date[0] + ' hours ') : ('');
   result += date[1] ? (date[1] + ' miutes ') : ('');
   result += date[2] ? (date[2] + ' seconds ') : ('');

   return result;
}

stringify('00:05:20'); // "5 miutes 20 seconds "
stringify('03:05:20'); // "3 hours 5 miutes 20 seconds "
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can convert your time in secondes and do it like with this function:

```
    alert(secondsToHms("00:05:20"));
  function secondsToHms(time) {
        var timeExtract = /(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/g.exec(time);

        d = Number(timeExtract[1] * 3600 + timeExtract[2] * 60 + timeExtract[3]);
        var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
        var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
        var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);
        return ((h > 0 ? h + " hours " + (m < 10 ? "0" : "") : "") + m + " minutes " + (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s); }
```

Comment: The input format is "00:05:20", not a number of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
var time = "00:05:20";
var regex = /(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})/g;
var timeString = time.replace(regex, "$1 Hours $2 Minutes $3 Seconds")
alert(timeString);
```